# Is there a word for this concept (related to awareness)?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

Let's suppose that I have the following sentence:

> "The population is extremely aware of subject *X*".

What would be the best (formal) way of conveying the same idea with the following way:

> "*X* is a topic that ...... by the population".

In "aware", the intended meaning is of being watchful (but not necessarily wary).

Comment: Due to their origins, many *be aXXX* predicates have grammatical restrictions which similar predicates are free from. Why do you need the *by*? What's the purpose for your reformulation containing a prepositional phrase using *by* plus your original sentence's subject? Are you trying to figure out an active verb to make passive despite having no direct object to promote to the grammatical subject? That would be as unlikely as passivizing *Beware the crouching tiger!* would be. Or is this to figure out how to refer to some property that you need a noun for not a verb so like *awareness level*?

Comment: *Aware* normally means something less active than *watchful*. *Aware* means you notice if something happens, but *watchful* means you're actively watching and checking to see if it happens. *wary* has wildly different definitions in Merriam-Webster and Lexico: "marked by keen caution, cunning, and watchfulness especially in detecting and escaping danger" vs "Feeling or showing caution about possible dangers or problems." I'd definitely take wary to mean the latter - cautious or afraid without necessarily keeping close watch, and certainly not cunning.

Comment: What’s a word that means the same as “bat”? Well, that depends on what meaning of “bat” you’re interested in. Maybe everybody else in the room is telepathic, but I don’t understand what you are asking. Consider, for the United States: The population is extremely aware of terrorism, because the 20-year anniversary of 9/11 is two days away, and the Taliban has been much in the news lately. But also, the population is extremely aware of football. The 2021-2022 season starts tonight, and it’ll be the first time in 20 months that there have been games with no COVID restrictions.  Which do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options are:

- "*X is a topic that engages the population*"
- "*X is a topic that speaks to the population*"
- "*X is a topic that interests the population*"
- "*X is a topic that matters to the population*"

Comment: As good as any, rewriting wise.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to change your sample sentence a bit, I suggest either of these captures the concept:

*X is a topic **on the public's mind**.*

or

*X is a topic **on people's minds**.*

**on someone's mind**

> occupying someone's thoughts [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/on-someones-mind)

These go further than simply being of interest.

---

> And Texas has big business **on its mind**. Home to 36 of the Fortune
> 500 companies, it is considered the energy capital of the world.
> [*Black Enterprise, Vol 24, no. 11*](https://www.google.com/search?q=The%20public%20had%20education%20%22on%20its%20mind%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvJKmNtRUrpbzvt7Fu4g1QXJ_oI6sQ:1631153948377&ei=HG85YauZFszl5NoP1NyymAo&start=30&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwirl6r96fDyAhXMMlkFHVSuDKM4FBDw0wN6BAgBEFM&biw=856&bih=395&dpr=1.5) p.192 (1994)

And of course "Georgia on My Mind" by Ray Charles.

Answer (score 0):

X is a topic that is actively monitored by the population

Comment: I think "actively monitored" is a step or two beyond "aware of"

Comment: The question says that *aware* means "watchful" which is a step beyond what I'd normally consider *aware* to mean ("conscious of"). So this is a reasonable attempt to guess what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

X is a topic thats on the news.